# Синхронизация Gitlab-а и Github-а

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Как синхронизировать содержимое репозиториев локального Gitlaba с Githubом?

Например, чтобы при добавлении коммита в Gitlab то же самое появилось в Github.

Comment: Никто не мешает Вам добавить себе два origin'а и коммтить в тот репозиторий, в который хочется. И в два одновременно.

Comment: Да хоть по cron-у вытягивать из гитлаба и пушить на гитхаб.

Или on-commit hook.

Answer (score 2):

1. можно одной командой `push` отправлять изменения сразу в несколько репозиториев: [Отправить изменения в несколько репозиториев одной командой push](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/499738/178576)
2. если сервер с *gitlab* вам подконтролен, то можно там в репозитории создать *post-commit hook*, который будет вызываться при поступлении коммитов в этот репозиторий. переработанный и дополненный [пример](http://blog.cloud-mes.com/2013/04/05/setup-mirror-between-2-or-more-git-server-using-hooks-script/):

   1. от имени пользователя, под которым выполняется *gitlab*, сгенерируйте пару приватный-публичный ключ:

      ```
      $ sudo -u пользователь ssh-keygen
      ```
   2. публичную часть ключа (файл `id_rsa.pub` в каталоге `.ssh` в домашнем каталоге того самого пользователя) добавьте к ключам вашего аккаунта на *github*-е.
   3. в каталоге с репозиторием на сервере с *gitlab*-ом от имени того же пользователя добавьте новый *remote* с произвольным именем (например, `togithub`):

      ```
      $ sudo -u пользователь git remote add --mirror=push togithub url-репозитория-на-github-е
      ```
   4. в том же каталоге в подкаталоге `hooks` создайте файл с именем `post-commit` такого содержания:

      ```
      #!/bin/sh
      exec git push togithub -f --mirror
      ```

      и установите ему биты исполнимости:

      ```
      $ sudo chmod +x hooks/post-commit
      ```