# Отправить изменения в несколько репозиториев одной командой push

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

В своём локальном репозитории можно подключить несколько удалённых репозиториев (`git remote add ...`) и отправлять в них изменения командой `git push имя-репозитория имя-ветки` — по одной команде на каждый репозиторий.

А как это сделать **одной** командой `git что-то-там`? без написания скрипта или функции или псевдонима (*alias*-а).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

для каждого удалённого репозитория можно задать *pushurl*, т.е., *url*, по которому будут отправляться изменения по команде *push*.

этот *pushurl*, кстати, может и не совпадать с *url* данного репозитория. вот такой фокус: делаете *push*, вроде бы, в репозиторий на *bitbucket*-е, а изменения идут на *github*.

более того: таких *pushurl*-ов может быть больше одного. и изменения одной командой отправятся сразу по нескольким *url*-ам.

добавляется *pushurl* с помощью команды примерно такого содержания:

```
$ git remote set-url --add --push имя-репозитория url-репозитория
```

---

#### от теории к практике.

создадим три (чтоб наверняка) bare-репозитория:

```
$ for i in 1 2 3; do git init --bare repo$i; done
Initialized empty Git repository in ./repo1/
Initialized empty Git repository in ./repo2/
Initialized empty Git repository in ./repo3/
```

и сделаем клон первого из них:

```
$ git clone repo1 work
Cloning into 'work'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.
$ cd work
```

посмотрим умолчальную конфигурацию *remote*-ов:

```
$ git config --get-regexp "^remote"
remote.origin.url ../repo1
remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

а теперь добавим *pushurl*-ы для всех созданных bare-репозиториев, не забыв и про сам исходный репозиторий (`../repo1`):

```
$ for i in 1 2 3; do git remote set-url --add --push origin ../repo$i; done
$ git config --get-regexp "^remote"
remote.origin.url ../repo1
remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.pushurl ../repo1
remote.origin.pushurl ../repo2
remote.origin.pushurl ../repo3
```

как видно, *pushurl*-ы благополучно добавились.

создаём коммит и отправляем его командой *push*:

```
$ date > file
$ git add file
$ git commit -m 1
[master (root-commit) 2d68407] 1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file
$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 228 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../repo1
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 228 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../repo2
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 228 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../repo3
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

вуаля! коммит отправился во все три bare-репозитория одной командой!

#### а как насчёт других веток?

создадим ещё одну ветку (`new`), добавим в неё коммит и отправим изменения:

```
$ git checkout -b new
Switched to a new branch 'new'
$ date >> file
$ git commit -am 2
[new c82bfe5] 2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ git push -u origin new
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 264 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../repo1
 * [new branch]      new -> new
Branch new set up to track remote branch new from origin.
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 264 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../repo2
 * [new branch]      new -> new
Branch new set up to track remote branch new from origin.
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 264 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../repo3
 * [new branch]      new -> new
Branch new set up to track remote branch new from origin.
```

эта «магия» работает и с новыми ветками! коммит отправился в ветки `new` во всех трёх bare-репозиториях.

---

ответ основан на информации из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290145/4827341) и [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195446/4827341) ответов.

Comment: А как такое же сделать для отдельных веток? Хочу, чтобы master в repo1, repo2, repo3, а new в repo2.

Comment: Отличная реализация! Кто будет это изучать, пользуйтесь работает как и должно!

Answer (score 1):

Если вкратце.

```
// Добавляем
git remote add "all" git@github.com:fudeglan/gigalab.uz.git  

git remote set-url --add --push "all" git@github.com:fudeglan/gigalab.uz.git
git remote set-url --add --push "all" git@bitbucket.org:fudeglan/gigalab.uz.git
git remote set-url --add --push "all" git@gitlab.com:fudeglan/gigalab.uz.git

// Отправляем
git push all
```

`.git/config` примерно будет таким

```
[remote "all"]
    url = git@github.com:fudeglan/gigalab.uz.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/all/*
    pushurl = git@github.com:fudeglan/gigalab.uz.git
    pushurl = git@bitbucket.org:fudeglan/gigalab.uz.git
    pushurl = git@gitlab.com:fudeglan/gigalab.uz.git
```