# Установка веток по умолчанию для git push/git pull

Tags: git, git-push, git-branch, git-pull, git-remote

Во время изучения git столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

1) Я могу задать ветку как ветку по умолчанию для `git pull` с помощью `git branch --set-upstream-to remoteRep/remoteBranch` находясь на этой ветке.

2) Сделать её веткой "не по умолчанию" для `git pull` могу с помощью `git branch --unset-upstream`.

3) Сделать её веткой по умолчанию для `git push` могу при выполнении `git push -u remoteRep remoteBranch`

4) А как убрать её статус `tracked` для `git push`?

---

Почему `--unset-upstream` не убирает ветку для `git push`?

```
git init
git remote add tr https://github.com/wcobalt/testrepo.git
git pull tr master
git remote show tr
* внешний репозиторий tr
  URL для извлечения: https://github.com/wcobalt/testrepo.git
  URL для отправки: https://github.com/wcobalt/testrepo.git
  HEAD ветка: master
  Внешние ветки:
    b1     отслеживается
    master отслеживается
  Локальная ссылка, настроенная для «git push»:
    master будет отправлена в master (уже актуальна)
git branch --unset-upstream
fatal: Ветка «master» не имеет информации о вышестоящей ветке
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

команды *push* и *pull* делят между собой одну и ту же пару конфигурационных параметров: имя хранилища и имя ветки.

эта пара используется, если не указана явно при выполнении команды.

пример из конфигурационного файла хранилища:

```
$ grep -A 1 master .git/config 
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

параметр `remote` («полное» имя, которое можно использовать для `git config` — `branch.ветка.remote`) — содержит имя хранилища, а параметр `merge` («полное» имя — `branch.ветка.merge`) — содержит имя ветки в этом хранилище.

---

невозможно для `pull` и `push` указать **разные** ветки (в удалённом хранилище) — нет двух **разных** параметров (типа `merge-для-pull` и `merge-для-push`).

точно так же невозможно «привязать» ветку (сделать «tracked») по отдельности для `push` и `pull`. приведённые вами в пунктах 1 и 3 команды являются синонимами (выдержка из `man git-branch`):

> ```
> git branch (--set-upstream-to=<upstream> | -u <upstream>) [<branchname>]
> ```

(технически они добавляют два параметра `remote` и `merge` в секцию `[branch "ветка"]`)

точно так же невозможно «отвязать» ветку (сделать «untracked») по отдельности для `push` и `pull`. приведённая вами в пункте 2 команда `git branch --unset-upstream [<branchname>]` сделает невозможным вызов (без явного указания хранилища и ветки) как `pull`, так и `push` (технически она просто удалит оба параметра `remote` и `merge`).

---

**дополенение** по поводу дополнения вопроса, начиная с:

> Почему `--unset-upstream` не убирает ветку для `git push`?

вы инициализировали новое хранилище, привязали к нему удалённое хранилище (под именем `tr`). ни одна ветка в локальном хранилище пока не связана («tracked») ни с одной удалённой веткой. в чём можно убедиться, как заглянув в `.git/conig` (ни одной секции `[branch "имя"]` в нём нет), так и попытавшись выполнить `push` или `pull` (без явного указания параметрами имени хранилища и имени ветки).

выполнив команду `git pull имя-хранилища имя-ветки`, вы получили состояние указанной ветки. но всё ещё ни одна локальная ветка не стала связанной ни с одной удалённой (содержимое `.git/config` не изменилось).

а раз нет связанной ветки, то нечего и «отвязывать». про что вам и говорит команда `branch --unset-upstream`:

> fatal: Ветка «master» не имеет информации о вышестоящей ветке

Comment: просто к слову: командой `push` можно [отправлять изменения сразу в несколько хранилищ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/499738/178576), но всё-таки в **одну и ту же ветку**.

Comment: А почему после `git branch --set-upstream` появляется строка только в `pull` (видно если выполнить `git remote show remoteRepo`) и то же самое с `--unset-upstream`?

Comment: 1. для `push` и `pull` используется **одна и та же** пара параметров (имя хранилища и имя ветки в нём). невозможно сделать для этих команд «разные конфигурации». 2. если что-то осталось непонятым, дополните, ваш вопрос, внеся в него [mcve].

Comment: Но если ветки не связаны с удаленными почему в выводе `git remote show tr` написано что они отслеживаются?

Comment: 1. это написано про *remote branches*, а не про *local*. 2. про *local* вообще-то написано не соответствующее истине утверждене (`master pushes to master`). подозреваю, это просто ошибка. 3. вместо дискуссий в комментариях здесь принято задавать новые вопросы.

Comment: послал [сообщение об ошибке](https://public-inbox.org/git/7871821540204990@iva3-0d9a30469759.qloud-c.yandex.net/).