# Синхронизация с другим git-репозиторием с добавлением только новых изменений

Tags: git

Нужно сделать репозиторий-клон, в котором изменить функционал в одной части, и иметь возможность подтягивать изменения, происходящие в исходном репозитории. Но так, чтобы после этих подтягиваний не затирались изменения функционала в репозитории-клоне. Достаточно ли для этого в клоне прописать remote на исходный репозиторий (к примеру, `baseOrigin`) и время от времени делать `git pull baseOrigin` / `git fetch baseOrigin`?

Comment: для fetch — достаточно. [для pull — нет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/895883/178576). вы как-то определитесь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я вижу, что вы новичок. Постарался написать максимально просто, но без глубокого погружения.

Краткая суть: бранчуемся, дорабатываем, по мере выхода новых релизов оригинала делаем fetch, мержим или переносим отдельные коммиты.

Алгоритм работы в вашем случае такой (пример на реальном репо).

### 1. Клонируем репозиторий

```
git clone https://github.com/dbfun/sql-samples
```

Смотрим, какие репозитории есть (так как только что склонировали, у нас там будет только один)

```
git remote -v

# вот что увидим:
origin  https://github.com/dbfun/sql-samples (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/dbfun/sql-samples (push)
```

Мы можем оставить "оригинал" как origin. Или переименовать в удобное для нас имя, `baseOrigin`:

```
git remote rename origin baseOrigin
```

Смотрим, что получилось

```
git remote -v

# вот что увидим:
baseOrigin  https://github.com/dbfun/sql-samples (fetch)
baseOrigin  https://github.com/dbfun/sql-samples (push)
```

Я бы оставил как `origin`, но это дело удобства. Это будет именно тот репо, в который сторонние разработчики будут что-то добавлять, а мы - получать и "подливать" себе.

Мы можем хранить свой кастомный репозиторий прямо здесь, на диске (каталог `.git`), куда был `git clone`, а можем добавить еще один удаленный, например, для "бекапа".

```
# Создаем пустой удаленный репозиторий. В этом примере - на диске:
git init --bare /home/totalpusher/gits/sql-samples-backup.git
# добавляем этот репо под именем backup
git remote add backup /home/totalpusher/gits/sql-samples-backup.git
# пушим ветку master в репо backup
git push backup master
```

### 2. Создаем ветку со своим функционалом

Этот шаг не обязателен, можно продолжать работать в master. Он становится нужным, когда идет параллельная разработка, тогда каждую "фишку" выносят в отдельную ветку, тестируют, и в дальнейшем сливают с master, а ветка master является "финишной", чистовой работой, которая публикуется на сервера приложений.

```
# переходим в каталог
cd sql-samples/
# бранчуемся
git checkout -b my-new-feature
```

Далее вносим любые свои изменения, коммитим. Теперь код работает в соответствии с нашими хотелками.

### 3. Обновляем ветку baseOrigin/master

Допустим, разработчики что-то сделали, и в итоге `baseOrigin/master` обновился. Мы все еще в ветке `my-new-feature`. Вот что мы делаем:

```
# обновляем ветку master из удаленного репо:
git fetch baseOrigin/master
# также можно использовать git fetch baseOrigin - будут получены все ветки
# или git fetch --all - будет обновлены из всех репо все ветки
# так можем посмотреть, что было сделано разработчиками "оригинала":
git log baseOrigin/master
```

Для краткости я не буду расписывать, как посмотреть, какие файлы, в каких местах менялись. Просто используйте привычные команды и указывайте `baseOrigin/master`.

Так как мы все еще в ветке `my-new-feature`, в рабочем каталоге видим свои изменения. А только что подтянутые изменения из `baseOrigin` "находятся" в каталоге `.git` в формате гита.

### 4. Подливаем изменения, внесенные разработчиками

Теперь нам нужно "подлить" из `baseOrigin/master` в нашу ветку `my-new-feature`.

Это можно делать двумя способами:

#### Первый способ: git merge

```
git merge baseOrigin/master --no-commit
```

Я специально указал ключ `--no-commit`, чтобы не было автоматического слияния. Сделайте `git status` и увидите те изменения, которые были применены. Их можно подправить с помощью разных команд гита типа `git reset HEAD ...`, `git checkout ...`.

Подробнее можно прочитать в мане: `man git-reset`, `man git-checkout` или найти в интернете.

Если будут конфликты, git их пометит. В конце, после исправлений, нужно все добавить и закоммитить (`git add ...`, `git commit ...`).

Будет создан коммит слияния, в который войдут:

- исправления внесенных разработчиками конфликтов с вашим подправленным кодом
- ваши дополнительные доработки, которые вы решите внести в "подлитый" код

#### Второй способ: git cherry-pick

Это - способ переноса отдельных коммитов в свою ветку. Допустим, разработчики сделали три коммита, вы ознакомились с ними, но реально вам нужен только один. В этом случае `git cherry-pick` - ваш выбор.

Смотрим хеши коммитов:

```
git log baseOrigin/master
```

Допустим, выбрали коммит с хешом `0127e07aaea9b97e8ced11759b8301ff7f581df3`. Напомню, мы все еще находимся в ветке `my-new-feature`.

```
git cherry-pick 0127e07aaea9b97e8ced11759b8301ff7f581df3 --no-commit
```

Я снова использовал ключ `--no-commit`, чтобы не мержить автоматически. Кстати, можно использовать сокращение хеша, гит "угадывает" по первым нескольким символам.

Теперь нам нужно проделать ту же работу, что при `git merge`, см выше. В конце нужно закоммитить этот слияние.

Подробности: `man git-cherry-pick`

### 5. Смотрим историю объединений

Для удобного просмотра использовать эту команду:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph
```

Пока я писал и проверял, у меня вышло вот что:

```
* 3fd5f1e (HEAD -> my-new-feature) bar
*   497085b Merge remote-tracking branch 'baseOrigin/master' into my-new-feature
|\  
| * 54ce1e7 test
* | 95445da mytest
* |   7e9e053 Merge remote-tracking branch 'baseOrigin/master' into my-new-feature
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 5b401f9 10
| * 325f8db 9
| * 16b3319 8
* |   6efe6a9 Merge remote-tracking branch 'baseOrigin/master' into my-new-feature
|\ \  
| |/  
| * e84e620 test
* |   1ee25b3 Merge remote-tracking branch 'baseOrigin/master' into my-new-feature
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 3522640 done 6
| * a70b63e done 5
| * 3ba1d1f done
* |   1444b6a Merge branch 'master' of /tmp/sql-origin/sql-samples into my-new-feature
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 247e562 done
* |   6bd3322 Merge branch 'master' of /tmp/sql-origin/sql-samples into my-new-feature
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 126c262 done
* | 37192dc done
|/  
* 08a6471 (backup/master, master) Создание уникального ID сертификата в формате год-месяц-номер
* 1d3a4c4 перевод в markdown
```

Comment: Благодарю за подробное описание. Меня интересует именно ветка master на репозитории-дубле. Нужно, чтобы ветка master дубля имела свое развитие, но принимала в себя все изменения (либо некоторые, видимо, с помощью cherry-pick, как вы написали) ветки master исходного репозитория.

Comment: В этом случае пропустите шаг бранчевания. Сразу работайте в ветке `master`.

Comment: Хмм... Pusher в нике наверное попытка перевести на английский "тот, кто делает команду push"?