# Синхронизация внешнего и внутреннего репозиториев

Tags: git

У меня есть репозиторий, сотоящий из нескольких директорий. Одна из директорий также является отдельным репозиторием. Как сделать так, чтобы коммиты в эту директорию учитывались в общем репозитории, а также коммиты в общий репозиторий в эту директорию учитывались в репозитории директории?

Comment: Ну, это вам автомердж нужен, так?

Comment: @InDevX нет, надо чтобы такой же коммит произошёл в 2 репозиториях, только пути для изменения файлов разные. Например, если во внутренний репозиторий X/A добавляю файл F, то для репозитория X был бы автоматический коммит с добавлением X/A/F

Comment: @InDevX хотя может это и называется "автомердж", не знаю

Comment: Насколько я понял, вам что-то [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/967930/330342) нужно. Там выше развернутый ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то вы говорите о том, что вам нужно построить схему с вложенными git репозиториями (одна папка гит репозитория также должна являться репозиторием). В общем случае гит не позволяет такого сделать.

Но вы можете посмотреть в сторону использования [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8) или [git subtree](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree). Эти два инструмента имеют немного разную реализацию, но дадут примерно тот эффект, на который вы рассчитываете.

Comment: Или Gerrit + repo...