# Как легко переключаться между github и bitbucket в git

Tags: git

У меня есть репозитории на GitHub и на bitbucket. Могу ли я пушить при помощи git изменения с одной локальной папки, являющейся проектом и лежащей на компьютере, все файлы на обе платформы. Если да, то как. Ответа в гугле не нашел, видимо потому что гуглил неправильно. Спасибо

Comment: да, добавьте два разных remote через git remote add, и указывайте имя ремоута при git push.

Comment: @PashaPash, [можно и не указывать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/499738/178576)