# Как в PHPStorm настроить push сразу в 2 репозитория?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm, git-push, jetbrains

На данный момент при push шторм предлагает выбрать в который реп отправлять,  но в оба сразу не предлагает.  Если 2 репозитория внутри одного проекта, тогда всё хорошо, и предлагает пушить сразу в оба.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/499738/178576

Comment: как просто в 2 репа пушить из командной строки я знаю,   но как это настроить в интерфейсе ide phpstorm ?

Comment: Добавляешь вторую репу: `Git | Manage Remotes...`. Нажимаешь `Ctrl+K`.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov я тоже думал что так будет работать, но оно выдает один реп для пуша, но в названии репа, можно выбирать один из двух, или добавить 3ий.  Честно говоря начинаю склоняться что это какой то баг шторма, или же где то волшебная галка заставляет пушить и коммитить только в один.